# SQL: Getting table/data information

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if someone could please enlighten me with a way to retrieve table information including information on the actual present data the table is storing... I am using **SQL Server 2008 R2** and below is the current script i have made...

```
SELECT
Sch.name AS 'Schema',
Tb.Name AS 'Table',
C.Name AS 'Column',
Tp.Name AS 'Type',
C.max_length,
C.precision,
C.scale
FROM Sys.Tables Tb
JOIN Sys.Schemas Sch
ON Sch.Schema_Id = Tb.Schema_Id
JOIN Sys.Columns C
ON C.Object_Id = Tb.Object_Id
JOIN Sys.Types Tp
ON Tp.System_Type_Id = C.System_Type_Id
WHERE Tp.name = 'numeric'
AND C.scale > 4
ORDER BY Sch.name ASC, Tb.name ASC, C.name ASC
```

This script retrieves all the information i require for every table i have in my DB. Then i have another script which i am manually inputting the table and columns i want information from.

```
SELECT 'Numeric Count' AS CounterType
, MAX(LEN(CAST(FLOOR(beca_proy_precio) AS VARCHAR(38)))) AS '1'
, MAX(LEN(CAST(FLOOR(beca_proy_precio_dol) AS VARCHAR(38)))) AS '2'
, MAX(LEN(CAST(FLOOR(beca_proy_tc) AS VARCHAR(38)))) AS '3'
FROM Comercial.beca_proyectada

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Decimal Count' AS CounterType
, MAX(LEN(CAST(REVERSE(STUFF(CAST(beca_proy_precio % 1 AS VARCHAR(38)), 1, 2, '')) AS DECIMAL(38, 0)))) AS '1'
, MAX(LEN(CAST(REVERSE(STUFF(CAST(beca_proy_precio_dol % 1 AS VARCHAR(38)), 1, 2, '')) AS DECIMAL(38, 0)))) AS '2'
, MAX(LEN(CAST(REVERSE(STUFF(CAST(beca_proy_tc % 1 AS VARCHAR(38)), 1, 2, '')) AS DECIMAL(38, 0)))) AS '3'
FROM Comercial.beca_proyectada
```

What this does is it gets the longest NOT LARGEST (whole and decimal portions seperately) numeric value in the columns specified. It then returns the length of the longest whole and decimal number.

For example:
Row 1 - 940.34910 => 3 whole number, 4 decimals
Row 2 - 1.1304902 => 1 whole numbers, 7 decimals

Therefore in this case it would return 3 for the longest whole number and 7 for the longest decimal number

Finally to clarify what i am looking to do is:
Join the 2 scripts where the 2nd script would get the values for each table/column the 1st script returns... outputting something like this:

Schema / Table / Column / Type / Max Length / Precision / Scale / Longest Whole / Longest Decimal

Thanks in advance for any help provided!!

Comment: You can constuct and execute sql from your query above using [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Im not exactly sure what you mean... If i run it like that id haveto still put in the parameters while i execute it as a SP... I want it to dynamically load the the data while the 1st script is executing... each row is a column for a table in that script therefore i want the 2nd script to load the information for that specific column...

Comment: You can dinamically build queries. To do so, declare cursor that reads from your schema-definition query and build select in some varchar variable. When done, call sp_executesql to give you results. It is hard and prone to errors, but I cannot think of another way. P.S. be sure to check the example at the bottom of the page to see how commands are built.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of work.

Create a temporary table to hold your results and the information

Fill it up with your schema data from the query with insert into

Then use a cursor and exec()

e.g. This one lists out all the tables in the current db and how many records in them.

```
Create #Results (TableName VarChar(255) not null, TableCount null)

insert into #Results(TableName) Select Name From Sys.Tables

Declare @TableName VarChar(255)
Declare @QueryString VarChar(255)
Declare TableNameCursor Cursor For Select TableName From #Results
Open TableNameCursor
Fetch Next From TableNameCursor Into @TableName
While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
  Select @QueryString = 'Declare @rc int Select @rc = Count(*) From ' + @TableName + ' + Insert #Results Select ''' + @TableName + ''',@rc'
  Exec(@QueryString)
  Fetch Next From TableNameCursor Into @TableName 
End
Close TableNameCursor
DeAllocate TableNameCursor

Select * from #Results
```

Tip, while you are figuring things out replace Exec(@QueryString) with Print @QueryString, you can get in right mess with the quotes.

Oh and the query you are execing has it's own scope, it can see @rc, but not @TableName.